# Addressing an observation which exceeds Cook's Distance

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, outliers, cooks-distance

During my data analysis, I've been modelling the effect of 13 predictor variables on one response variable, house prices. When looking into possible transformations for my predictor variables, I was focusing on one variable in particular, and modelled a linear regression of this particular variable on the response. I found from the diagnostic plots, that there was one observation which exceeded Cook's Distance, see below:
[image: Outlier]

Now I wonder what the appropriate action is? When you model the full regression model using all variables, this particular observation is not considered an outlier by Cook's Distance, but in this simplified model, it is. Should I look to remove it? Any suggestions?

UPDATE: When I apply a transformation of square rooting the variable, not only does the full model improve (by $R^2), but the outlier no longer exceeds Cook's Distance. Does this mean this transformation is good?

Comment: Not to mention that 406, 419 and others seem to scale this particular plot very strangely...